# Extend logs for SharePoint on-premsies and Online more than 90 days

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-on-prem, administration

Is there a way to preserve the logs files for more than 90 days for SharePoint online and SharePoint on-premises and define specific site collection/s to have this extended logs?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Microsoft uses the Unified Logging System (ULS) in the SharePoint
> Online environment. Sometimes we receive requests to share these ULS
> logs with customers for troubleshooting and debugging scenarios.
> Microsoft does not provide copies of ULS logs or any access to ULS
> logs from SharePoint Online.

Ref: [Information about ULS log access for SharePoint Online](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/administration/information-about-uls-log-access)

> In the Number of days to store log files box, type the number of days
> (1-366) that you want logs to be kept. After this time, logs will
> automatically be deleted.

Ref: [Configure diagnostic logging in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/configure-diagnostic-logging)

[image]